# Speed up query with large table DESC limit 1

Tags: mysql

MariaDB 10 (myisam)

Query executes rather slowly, takes about 90 seconds.

I tried deleting some old rows and then optimizing the table.

```
SELECT ceil(rate * 8 / 1000000)
FROM db.Octets
WHERE id = 5344
order by datetime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Query takes a really long time to execute.

```
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table          | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | Octets         | index | NULL          | Octets_1_idx     | 8       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Obviously you need an index on `id`  and on `datetime`. Do you have that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try adding a  composite redundant  index

```
create index  idx2 on Octets ( id , datetime, rate)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this essentially just double the size of the table? I tried it, the result was: Query OK, 41261518 rows affected (57.90 sec) the explain said it had to search through 1086338 rows to find it still.

Comment: How many rows there are in table?  and how many rows  match thw where id = 5344?

Comment: yes, it is essentially. But i have seen that you using MyISAM. There are many write on this table. Each write locks the whole table. MyISAM has only table lock. InnoDB has row lock.

Comment: So should I convert the tables to innodb?

Comment: also  ..  you can try  creating a copy of the table using innodb  create ()  ENGINE=InnoDB attribute and test  ..the performance with the different option suggested

Comment: Would be cool if there was someway to just index the last row in the table so it always just knows which one to look at.

Comment: for obatin the last rows  ,,  you need  an order by on all the selected  rows ..  and filter for the last